# ERROR INSTALLING KIVY: Why am I Getting Error After Executing: "python -m pip install kivy"?

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip, kivy

I've been trying to install kivy on my machine (windows10) but I got the big error message and here is a part of it:

> ```
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\budim\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\budim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bur_n_r3\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\budim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bur_n_r3\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-gd8fylih'
> cwd: C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bur_n_r3\kivy\
> Complete output (388 lines):
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\budim\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\budim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-no3k1_h3\\cython\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\budim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-no3k1_h3\\cython\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-x41teyf2'
> cwd: C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-no3k1_h3\cython\
> Complete output (321 lines):
> ```

I think that is the most important part(I can't put the whole error because it's huge)

Here are the commands that I executed:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 
kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
python -m pip install pygame
python -m pip install kivy
```

P.S. I get the error after executing the last command

Can anyone explain to me why is this happening?

Comment: I know you probably did, but have you ran cmd/powershell as administrator?

Comment: I ran normal cmd by searching cmd in windows search option, thanks for helping

Comment: @Marko Is the problem solved? Have you seen my answer?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 Sorry for replying this late, I did not succeed in solving the problem, after changing the last command to: "python -m pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip", at first everything seemed ok but after "Getting requirements to build wheel" output I got an pkg-config.exe - Application error that the says: The application was unable to start correctly(0xc000007b). The exact same error I got after "Preparing wheel metadata" output. And then I got another huge error and kivy failed to install. Do you know what is the problem? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 I took a look on the link that you mentioned in your answer, it seems like I don't have the same errors as mentioned on the page.

Comment: @Marko it seems like this could be another issue occurring due to some pre-requisites or dependency issues. I would suggest you to ask that as a new question and make sure to include the full error trace in the question and you can link me here to have a look at it. Meanwhile, If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 Here is a link to my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863792/error-installing-kivy-why-am-i-getting-error-after-executing-python-m-pip-ins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it may be related to this issue here - [Problem with installing kivy. Windows 10 #4991](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4991)

Instead of

```
python -m pip install kivy
```

do

```
python -m pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip
```

or clone it in and install that way.

Also, try and run your `cmd` line in an administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install kivy with python 3.10 version you would be  getting an error as the latest version has not yet acclimatized well to handle kivy.
It is not impossible to install kiwi on 3.10 version but it is an cumbersome process and also very messy...
I would rather recommend you to use 3.9.2 version of python which will enable you to install kivy without much issues...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the latest version of python, try using version **3.92** or older because some of the python libraries don't support the newer version of python.